# Bash command to check if the variable name is valid

Tags: linux, shell, naming-conventions, variable-names

```
#check if the name is valid
function myfunc()
{
    #check "${1}"
    #echo "valid/invalid"
}

#these should return valid
myfunc "my_number"
myfunc "my_number1"

#these should return ivalid 
myfunc "1my_number"
myfunc "1my _number"
myfunc "my number"
myfunc "my_number?"
```

and so on the variable name can have only letters , numbers (but not on the beginning),.. and like all the rules for java...

Is there any function that I can use ? I do not want to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Why do you think there would be a built in function in bash to check against variable name rules for Java? Different languages have different restrictions on what is allowed in a variable name. You are going to need to determine the rules for your language and environment yourself, and implement it with something like the regex that @dogbane suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Match the variable name against a regex, like this:

```
myfunc() {
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$ ]]
    then
        echo "$1: valid"
    else
        echo "$1: invalid"
    fi
}
```

Comment: `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$` would mark variables starting with an uppercase character invalid. May I suggest `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`?

Comment: I did that on purpose. Java convention is not to start variables with an uppercase, but it's up to the OP to decide. It wasn't in his test cases.

Comment: It's also legal to begin a varname with underscore, so `^[_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*$` If you want to match case-insensitively, you can `shopt -s nocasematch`

Answer (score 3):

[dogbane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294345/2305676) is almost complete for the context of bash variables, but it has not been updated to reflect the final comment which contains a fully working validator. According to his comment on his answer, this is intended. This answer provides a function which evaluates to true for all valid names and can be used as a condition rather than returning a value that must then be compared to something. Plus, it can be used across multiple shells.

The function:

```
isValidVarName() {
    echo "$1" | grep -q '^[_[:alpha:]][_[:alpha:][:digit:]]*$'
}
```

Example usage in bash:

```
key=...
value=...

if isValidVarName "$key"; then
    eval "$key=\"$value\""
fi


# or it might simply look like this

isValidVarName "$key" && eval "$key=\"$value\""
```

Comment: Why the "  && return || return 1" part? The return code of grep seems correct to me.

Comment: @OlivierPirson, you make an excellent point. I have no idea why I did that. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bash only:

```bash
isvalidvarname ()
{
    local varname;
    local regexp_varname='^[_[:alpha:]][_[:alpha:][:digit:]]*$';
    varname="$1";
    [[ "${varname}" =~ ${regexp_varname} ]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of already proposed answers.
For all shells, by using [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

```
is_valid_name() {  # NAME
    printf '%s' "$1" | grep --quiet '^[_[:alpha:]][_[:alpha:][:digit:]]*$'
}
```

For shells that accept regexp, like [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b):

```
function is_valid_name {  # NAME
    [[ "$1" =~ ^[_[:alpha:]][_[:alpha:][:digit:]]*$ ]]
}
```

Both return 0 (true) if NAME is a valid variable name, else return 1 (false).
They can be used like this:

```
NAME='...'
is_valid_name "$NAME" && ...
if is_valid_name "$NAME"; then
    ...
fi
```